# Kotlin: How can I create a "static" inheritable function?

Tags: function, kotlin

For example, I want to have a function `example()` on a type `Child` that extends `Parent` so that I can use the function on both.

```
Child.example()
Parent.example()
```

The first "obvious" way to do this is through the companion object of `Parent`, but this doesn't allow `example()` for `Child`.

The second way I tried was defining an extension function on `Parent.Companion`, which is inconvenient because you are forced to define a companion object. It also doesn't allow `example()` for `Child`.

Does anybody know how I can do this?

Comment: What's the point to make a static function inheritable???

Comment: @DanielTran Well it's not necessarily "static" since it's Kotlin. The purpose is to create an "alternative operator" to construction, like `Child[1, 2, 3]` instead of `Child(1, 2, 3)`

Comment: @DanielTran How about for instance enforcing factory methods for child classes?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

What you are asking for does not exist, you appear to be asking:

> Can I reference a companion object method of a superclass from a class reference of its descendants

or maybe you are asking:

> Can I reference a static member of a superclass from a reference of its descendants.

The answer for both is **no**.  It is **by design** of Kotlin that this is disallowed, was a conscious decision, was intentional.  If you wish to change this decision you would need to [file an issue in YouTrack](http://kotl.in/issue).  Programmers in Java were **heavily confused** by the inheritance and overriding of static methods and the behavior when called from one reference versus another and how it is statically resolved rather than dynamically. Java 8 team when adding static methods to interfaces realize the confusion this could cause so they took a more Kotlin approach of only allowing it to be called by the interface reference.  To avoid these types of nightmares, the Kotlin team disallowed it.  Just as they disallowed many other confusing aspects of Java.

The other answers (@voddan's for example) are giving you work-arounds to have the same feel of calling syntax by using [companion objects](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#companion-objects) but you reject those in your comments by saying you want to avoid a companion object, even though your question states you are trying to use them.  So assuming you do not want to use them, the answer is simply **no, can't be done**.

To get rid of the companion object, you would want to talk about [Can extension functions be called in a “static” way?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39312709/3679676) ... which will be disappointing since it is not yet allowed.

Going back to companion objects (sorry, but they are the one path to glory here), you can also just manually delegate the method of the child to the parent:

```
open class Parent {
    companion object { // required, sorry, no way around it!
        fun foo() = /* some cool logic here */
    }
}

class Child: Parent() {
    companion object {  // required, sorry, no way around it!
        fun foo() = Parent.foo() 
    }
}
```

Or as extensions:

```
open class Parent {
    companion object {} // required, sorry, no way around it!
}

class Child: Parent() {
    companion object {} // required, sorry, no way around it!
}

fun Parent.Companion.foo() = /* some cool logic here */
fun Child.Companion.foo() = Parent.foo()
```

Answer (score 18):

Since companion objects play by the same rules as any others, it is easy to use normal means of code reuse on them:

```
open class Example {
    fun example() {}
}

class Parent {
    companion object : Example()
}

class Child {
    companion object : Example()
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Child.example()
    Parent.example()
}
```

Alternatively with class delegation you can reuse the implementation from `Parent` directly:

```
interface Example {
    fun example()
}

class Parent {
    companion object : Example {
        override fun example() {}
    }
}

class Child {
    companion object : Example by Parent.Companion
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to get around having to define the companion object?

Comment: It may be a regular object ;)

Answer (score 0):

> The purpose is to create an "alternative operator" to construction

In Java you should use a Factory instead of a static method when used as a "constructor".

On the Kotlin side you could use a top-level-function instead of a Factory.

Or if you really want to have a "static method" in your class,
I'd create a companion object and add static extension methods.

Comment: All that you mentioned is right, but child classes can't use them.

Comment: Did you miss the import of the extension function? Static extension functions should be available in sub-classes when you have it imported

Comment: Sorry, I should have worded that better. I meant that you can't use them automatically for child classes. As in defining a function `example()` in the companion object of a parent called `Parent` will let you do `Parent.example()`; with a child of `Parent` called `Child`, you can't do `Child.example()` automatically.

Comment: You are right, its not even working with static extension functions