# Calling inner class in the parent not working in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-interop

I was in process of converting a java project to kotlin when I encountered this strange behavior.

in Java:

```
new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

works fine.

but in kotlin it gives me compile error:

```
ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)


LayoutParams is an inner class in `FrameLayout` which is the parent of `ImageSwitcher`
```

[image]

I know I can solve it by using `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` **but why the original code is not working?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no static inheritance in kotlin, and i guess this is the right way to go because static inheritance may lead to ambigous errors.

Comment: thank you, you pointed me in the right direction.  
I found this excellent answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/39303180/3998402