# How to call java static function in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I could not call java static function even after referring to [Possibility to call a Java static method in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28734510/possibility-to-call-a-java-static-method-in-kotlin)

I am new to Kotlin and Java, and i made a WearOS test code in kotlin.

```
import android.hardware.Sensor
import android.hardware.SensorEvent
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener
import android.hardware.SensorManager

....

class SensorActivity: Activity() {
    private var mSensor: Sensor? = null // import success

    ....
    
    fun myCode() {
        // i could not use getMaxLengthValuesArray
        val num = Sensor.getMaxLengthValuesArray(mSensor, sdkLevel);
    }
}
```

The getMaxLengthValuesArray is method of Sensor class which is declared in public
and the method is also public static.

**So i think i can access Sensor.getMaxLengthValuesArray according to the above ref [Possibility to call a Java static method in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28734510/possibility-to-call-a-java-static-method-in-kotlin), but it does not work.**

Is there something wrong with my understanding of Kotlin syntax?

Comment: That method is marked `@hide` so it is not available in the SDK.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you!!